# Creating Excel chart with VBA - wrong result

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I did sine calculator in Excel.
I try to insert chart into sheet.
The chart should be sine wave with Y-axis as Amplitude, and X-axis as Time.
The problem is that I get a chart with two graphs: sine, according to Y-column, and line - according to the X-column.
Here my code:

```
Public oneTimeFlag As Integer

Sub calc()

    Range("A3", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Clear
    Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Clear

    Range("A2").Value = "0"

    lw = Int(Range("$I$3").Value + 1)

    If lw >= 4 And lw < 21000 Then

        Range("A3").Select

        ActiveCell.Formula = "=(2*PI()/$I$3)+A2"

        Range("A3:A" & lw).FillDown

        Range("B2").Select

        ActiveCell.Formula = "=ROUNDDOWN(POWER(2,$G$2)/2 + SIN(($F$7*2*PI()/360) + A2)*((POWER(2,$G$2)/2) -1), 0)"

        Range("B2:B" & lw).FillDown

        AddOrUpdateChartSheet (lw)

    Else
        MsgBox "Nof points must be 4 at least and less than 21000!"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$5" Or Target.Address = "$F$6" Or Target.Address = "$F$7" Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
        Call calc
        rng.Select

    End If
End Sub

Sub AddOrUpdateChartSheet(ByVal lw As Integer)
    Dim chtChart As Chart
    If oneTimeFlag <> 1 Then
        oneTimeFlag = 1

        Set chtChart = Charts.Add
        Set chtChart = chtChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1")
        With chtChart            
            .ChartType = xlLine


            .SetSourceData (ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B" & lw))
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Sine"

            With .Parent 
              .Name = "Sine"
            End With
        End With


    Else    
        Dim objChrt As ChartObject        
        Dim sineChartExists As Boolean
        sineChartExists = False

        For Each objChrt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            If objChrt.Name = "Sine" Then
                sineChartExists = True
            End If
        Next

        If sineChartExists = False Then
            oneTimeFlag = 0
            AddOrUpdateChartSheet (lw)
        Else
            Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Sine")
            Set chtChart = objChrt.Chart

            With chtChart
                .SetSourceData (ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B" & lw))
            End With
        End If
    End If    
End Sub
```

I get something similar to:
[Chart with sine wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKRVM.png)

Clock frequency, divider and DAC resolution are constants.
User changes the Needed frequency, amplitude and phase.
The sheet automatic calculates the number of points, calculates points (time, dac_value) and according to number of points creates the needed chart.

As mentioned above, as a result I get chart with two graphs (X-axis is number of point, Y-axis - is amplitude (DAC value)).
I need chart with one graph only (sine), with X-axis as Time (Column A), and with Y-axis as Amplitude (Column B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear A1 before you create the chart and then reinstate the title afterwards:

```
Sub calc()

    Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Clear
    Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Clear

    lw = Int(Range("$I$3").Value + 1)

    If lw >= 4 And lw < 21000 Then
        Range("A2").Value = "0"

        Range("A3:A" & lw).Formula = "=(2*PI()/$I$3)+A2"

        Range("B2:B" & lw).Formula = "=ROUNDDOWN(POWER(2,$G$2)/2 + SIN(($F$7*2*PI()/360) + A2)*((POWER(2,$G$2)/2) -1), 0)"

        AddOrUpdateChartSheet lw
        Range("A1").Value = "X (Time)"

    Else
        MsgBox "Nof points must be 4 at least and less than 21000!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are right!! Thanks a lot!!
Could you please, explain the "magic trick" ?:)

Comment: It's an Excel oddity. If you have a header in the first column the chart wizard assumes it's a value series, not a category series. No idea why!

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot, again! You saved my mind - I spent full working day with trying to fix it...

Comment: XY Scatter charts are smarter than Line charts, when it comes to parsing out X from Y values.